# Want to have anchor link and elements within form tag in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and I need to have everything in the same line.

```
<a href="link.com">link</a>
<form method="post">
<input name="submit2" type="submit" class="icon2" value=" " style="display:inline"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="icon3" value=" " style="display:inline" />
</form>
```

How can I put the link and both buttons in the same line? Are there any CSS attributes that would do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display: inline` will, you just have to apply it to the form.

Comment: I tried that in the buttons cuz I know that it should work.. -.-' I was just about to get crazy.. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<form method="post">
<a href="link.com">link</a>
<input name="submit2" type="submit" class="icon2" value=" " style="display:inline"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="icon3" value=" " style="display:inline" />
</form>
```

EDIT: I think you can also remove the display:inline